# How to show that PDE is satisfied?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

[image]

How to solve this please?

Attempt:

$$a*\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial f} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = a(1)(\alpha) = a\alpha = (A) \\
b*\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial f} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = b(1)(\beta) = b\beta = (B)
$$

Therefore $(A)+(B) = aα + bß$ is the differential equation. I'm stuck from here (assuming I've done everything else correctly which I may not have). Thanks! I get very confused when performing partial differentiation where a function equals another function like this case.

Comment: Note that $$a\alpha +b\beta=0$$

Comment: @MarkViola Hi Mark! So what I did was correct? I honestly didn't even know if I differentiated correctly, I don't understand why exactly ∂u/∂f = 1 and ∂f/∂x = alpha.  I'm new to multivariable calculus (started 2 days back) and it seems very interesting  but I still need to grasp concepts where a function = another function like here u(x,y) = f(ax+by). :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things wrong.  To make things clearer, we should name the unnamed function that takes $(x,y)$ to $\alpha x+\beta y,$ so let $h(x,y) =\alpha x+\beta y.$  Then $u(x,y) = f(h(x,y))$ and the chain rules look like

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{df}{dh} \frac{\partial h}{\partial x} = \frac{df}{dh}\alpha$$

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = \frac{df}{dh} \frac{\partial h}{\partial y} = \frac{df}{dh}\beta$$

Note the plain $d$'s on the derivative of $f$.  Those are not partial derivatives.

Plug these into the PDE to get

$$a\frac{df}{dh}\alpha +b\frac{df}{dh}\beta = 0.$$

Now you just have to find "suitable constants" $\alpha$ and $\beta.$
If $\frac{df}{dh}=0$, then any values for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ will do.  If not, you can divide through by it and get

$$a\alpha + b\beta = 0.$$

There are lots of solutions, but an easy one is $\alpha = b$ and $\beta = -a.$

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for your response! I was just wondering, how did you get ∂u/∂x = df/dh * ∂h/∂x in the first line of your equation? Thanks :)

Comment: It's the usual chain rule.  $f:R\to R$ and $h:R^2 \to R.$ and $u$ is their composition so $u:R^2 \to R.$  There are different notations for multivariable derivatives, and all have some flaw.  In an abuse of notation, $\partial u/\partial x = df/dx$, but it's not quite right because $f$ is not a function of $x$, but of $h$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
a\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(\alpha x +\beta y)+b\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(\alpha x +\beta y)\\
=(a \alpha+b \beta)f'(\alpha x +\beta y)=0 \\ 
\to \alpha=-{b \over a} \beta
$$